# akka-http client for GET request throwing cannot find local variable instance

Tags: akka, akka-http

I am creating an Akka HTTP client to make GET and POST requests. I am using a `Future`-based example from the documentation. I get an error which says, "cannot find local variable instance." Here is a simple code and test case.

```
package com.epl.akka
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{HttpMethods, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, StatusCodes}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, ActorMaterializerSettings}
import akka.util.ByteString
import com.epl.akka.AkkaHTTPClient.GET

class AkkaHTTPClient() extends Actor
  with ActorLogging {

  import akka.pattern.pipe
  import context.dispatcher

  final implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(context.system))

  val http = Http(context.system)

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case GET(uri: String) =>
      log.info("getting the url")
      http
        .singleRequest(HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET,uri = uri))
        .pipeTo(self)

    case HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, headers, entity, _) =>
      entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString(""))(_ ++ _).foreach { body =>
        log.info("Got response, body: " + body.utf8String)
      }

    case resp @ HttpResponse(code, _, _, _) =>
      log.info("Request failed, response code: " + code)
      resp.discardEntityBytes()
  }  
}

object AkkaHTTPClient {

  def props() =
    Props[AkkaHTTPClient]

  final case class GET(uri: String){}  
}
```

What the code does is crawl a URL and return the HTML response, which is then parsed by JSoup to create a JSON result.

Test Case:

```
class AkkaHTTPClientSpec(_system: ActorSystem)
  extends TestKit(_system)
  with Matchers
  with FlatSpecLike
  with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  def this() = this(ActorSystem("AkkaHTTPClientSpec"))

  override def afterAll: Unit = {
    shutdown(system)
  }

  "A AkkaHttpClient Actor" should "give HTML response when instructed to" in {
    val testProbe = TestProbe()

    val url = "http://www.premierleague.com"
    val akkaHTTPClientActor = system.actorOf(AkkaHTTPClient.props(),"AkkaHttpClient")
    akkaHTTPClientActor ! GET(url)
  }
}
```

The code fails after calling `val http = Http(context.system)`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the complete 'cannot find local variable instance' error message?

Answer (score 0):

I made the following minor changes to your code, and the test passed with Akka HTTP 10.0.10 and Scala 2.12:

1. Changed the URL to `http://akka.io`, because making a GET request to `http://www.premierleague.com` resulted in a 301 status code.
2. Changed the client code to send a "OK response" message to the original sender.
3. Mixed in the `ImplicitSender` trait into the spec and changed the test to expect an "OK response" message from the client.

The latter two changes I made in order to have a more meaningful test.

Below is the adjusted code that successfully runs. First, the client:

```scala
package com.epl.akka

import akka.actor._
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, ActorMaterializerSettings}
import akka.util.ByteString

import com.epl.akka.AkkaHTTPClient.GET

class AkkaHTTPClient() extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import akka.pattern.pipe
  import context.dispatcher

  final implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(context.system))

  val http = Http(context.system)

  var originalSender: Option[ActorRef] = None // <-- added

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case GET(uri: String) =>
      val s = sender             // <-- added
      originalSender = Option(s) // <-- added
      log.info("getting the url")
      http
        .singleRequest(HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET,uri = uri))
        .pipeTo(self)

    case HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, headers, entity, _) =>
      entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString(""))(_ ++ _).foreach { body =>
        log.info("Got response, body: " + body.utf8String)
      }
      originalSender.foreach(_ ! "OK response") // <-- added

    case resp @ HttpResponse(code, _, _, _) =>
      log.info("Request failed, response code: " + code)
      resp.discardEntityBytes()
  }
}

object AkkaHTTPClient {
  def props() = Props[AkkaHTTPClient]
  final case class GET(uri: String)
}
```

And the spec:

```scala
package com.epl.akka

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem}
import akka.testkit.{ImplicitSender, TestKit}

import com.epl.akka.AkkaHTTPClient.GET
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, FlatSpecLike, Matchers}

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class AkkaHTTPClientSpec(_system: ActorSystem)
  extends TestKit(_system)
  with ImplicitSender  // <-- added
  with Matchers
  with FlatSpecLike
  with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  def this() = this(ActorSystem("AkkaHTTPClientSpec"))

  override def afterAll: Unit = {
    shutdown(system)
  }

  "An AkkaHTTPClient Actor" should "give HTML response when instructed to" in {
    val url = "http://akka.io" // <-- changed
    val akkaHTTPClientActor = system.actorOf(AkkaHTTPClient.props(), "AkkaHttpClient")
    akkaHTTPClientActor ! GET(url)
    expectMsg(20.seconds, "OK response") // <-- added
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why is the sender needed here? The code i had was exact copy from akka doc

Comment: @SanjeevGhimire: As I mentioned in the answer, capturing the sender is simply for testing purposes.

Comment: but without the sender that is used for test purpose the code doesn't work.